# Any activity similar to "For Each" in Workflow Foundation?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-foundation

Iam new to WF. I could see If/Else ,While activities. Is there any activity to perform the "For Each" operation in  WF. Iam planning to passa  list of objects into the WF. I need to perform some operation on each of the objects.. What would be the best way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WF4 you have [ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647676) activity. 
In WF3 there is no such activity, but you can look at [Introduction to Sequential Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd692925.aspx) for a tutorial on how to iterate through a list of files. You can adapt that to your needs.

Comment: You could also consider using ParallelForEach activity.

Answer (score 1):

As said by Patko, WF4 has a Foreach activity. But since Iam working with WF3.5 , had to use Replicator activity instead.